# Running COM/DCOM based application on Linux via Wine

Tags: linux, windows, com, wine, dcom

I want to run a COM/DCOM based application on a Linux servers. Why Linux? 
Because 90 % of my stack is running on linux and my cluster manager is also linux friendly.

Would it be fair to use wine for it. I am not confident about the given application because it isn't part of wine application store. Is that even possible? Any recommendations?

Comment: Another way around this I might add, is to create an API using .NET, which would have access to COM/DCOM as needed. Then you can run this on the Windows machine and then Wine can interface with COM/DCOM via your API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked into this recently. Read this and I think the short answer is "not possible" - https://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/dcom-1

> In Wine, our DCOM implementation is not currently based on the RPC
>   runtime, as while few programs use DCOM even fewer use RPC directly so
>   it was developed some time after OLE32/OLEAUT32 were. Eventually this
>   will have to be fixed, **otherwise our DCOM will never be compatible
>   with Microsoft's.** Bear this in mind as you read through the code
>   however.